# How to take multiple data at checkbox value in php?

Tags: php, checkbox

Here I just grabbed the ID or a data in the check box. But I want to capture more data with the ID. How to do it?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="man" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

And how do I insert that data into another table via PHP MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set checkboxes name with array brackets.

Ex: `<input type="checkbox" name="man[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">`

After that if you get their values with `$_POST["man"]`, then an array with value of the checkboxes will be return.